# String of coordinates into an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a String with coordinates which looks like this:
(These coordinates are loaded from a text files and tells the position of entities)

```
String coords = "0,0 0,1 5,2 7,4 10,5"
```

My question is, how can I turn this String into an ArrayList of Points, where ID 0 is a Point(0,0) and so on?

I tried splitting the String, but without any real success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

1. Split coords using "whitespace"
2. Foreach resulting array
3. Split the pairs to x y
4. Parse strings to int
5. Create point
6. Add to list

---

```
String coords = "0,0 0,1 5,2 7,4 10,5"
String coordsArray[] = coords.split("\\s+") // Results "0,0","0,1","5,2","7,4","10,5"
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
for(String s : coordsArray)
{
    String coordXY[] = s.split(","); 
    int x = Integer.parseInt(coordXY[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(coordXY[1]);
    points.add(new Point(x,y));
}
```

Comment: +1, but, since these are being loaded from ASCII files, it might be prudent to use TryParse() and/or a try/catch. Who knows what an end-user will do..

Comment: Since I forget to look at tags a lot, I'm curious; is this really java code? It looks like C#. I've been hesitating to start another new language but if they're that similar...

Comment: @Jon It is Java. I had to check after i soo your comment :) I use both so much, that i sometimes try to mix em. But this is valid. As what comes to the answer, yes, there should be try catch or some precautions for the invalid entry. I can't address every situation in answer so i decided to stick to the actual problem.